# How to get data from a disable dynamic field in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, specflow

My html is as such

```
 <input type="textbox" id="TlNo" class="TlNo" style="display:block;" value="" disabled="">
```

The field is as follows

[image]

How can I get the value of this disable textbox?

Please note the value of this textbox will keep changing based on calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the value by adding the following `getAttribute("value")`

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("TlNo")).GetAttribute("value");
```

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary : OP can not do that, there's a cooling period of 24 hours, afterwards he can mark his own question accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one,

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("TlNo")).Text;
```